# android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication

Tags: react-native

I have use this command on my project:

`react-native upgrade`

And I'm getting the error when I try to build the app:

> android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication

I really don't know how to fix that. Any tip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the following to AndroidManifest.xml should solve the error:

```
 <application
   android:name=".MainApplication"
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, **Restarting my Android device** always solves the issue

Looks like it is a random error

Comment: For me also always

Comment: Strange error, restarting fixed my issue as well.