# React Native Initial Load Crashes without any error

Tags: windows, react-native

React Native android app is crashing at genymotion without throwing any error after finished the installation. Do you guys have any idea with this issue? RN version is 0.31 with windows 7 machine.

[image]

Comment: Open the android project in android folder in Android studio and let gradle sets up all the stuff for ya.

Comment: Usual upgrade issue. Found the fix for the same here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344843/android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to-com-facebook-react-reactapplication Thanks @abeikverdi