# How to remove the fadeout effect from the SplashScreen in Android using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I've been struggling trying to remove the fadeout effect before my first react native interface appear on the screen, but, until now, I don't get it.

I tried with this tutorial : https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154, but doesn't works.

I tried adding an SplashActivity as well, but it doesn't works.

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.cv;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "CV";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SplashScreen.show(this, false);  // here
    }
}
```

MainApplication

```
package com.cv;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;
import com.github.wuxudong.rncharts.MPAndroidChartPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new SvgPackage(),
            new MPAndroidChartPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cv">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@drawable/launch_screen"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
        >

      <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.cv.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my SplashActivity

```
package com.cv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.cv.MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        finish();
    }
}
```

package name is correct in build.gradle (inside app), manifest and class files.

I've been using this command to execute the application:

```
react-native run-android
```

and

```
react-native run-android --appId com.cv --main-activity SplashActivity
```

The output is:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 37s
108 actionable tasks: 40 executed, 68 up-to-date
Running /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1Z9N9S reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on CB5A1Z9N9S (/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1Z9N9S shell am start -n com.cv/com.cv.SplashActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.cv/.SplashActivity }
```

But, when the app opens, shows the splash, and suddenly closes, but in Logcat I got:

```
08-26 00:17:03.414 27240-27240/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-26 00:17:03.479 27240-27240/com.cv W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
08-26 00:17:03.549 27240-27240/com.cv W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-26 00:17:03.569 27240-27240/com.cv I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.cv time:38049157
08-26 00:17:03.613 27240-27240/com.cv D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-26 00:17:03.615 27240-27240/com.cv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cv, PID: 27240
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cv/com.cv.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.getReactNativeHost(ReactActivityDelegate.java:71)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:91)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:80)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:52)
        at com.cv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
08-26 00:17:07.542 27240-27240/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27240 SIG: 9
```

At this moment I don't know what to do exactly. Any idea?. Thanks.

My app dependencies:

```
"native-base": "^2.7.2",
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-native-animate-number": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.4.3",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-svg": "^6.5.1",
"react-native-timeline-listview": "^0.2.3",
"react-native-timer": "^1.3.4",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
"victory-native": "^30.1.0"
```

Node: 8.11.2
npm: 6.1.0
OS: Mac OS Sierra
Android Studio: 3.1.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344843/android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to-com-facebook-react-reactapplication)

Comment: I tried that as well, but AndroidStudio only shows MainActivity and SplashActivity, in spite of MainApplication is in the same directory. I think this is the key, but is not possible add it